# Write/create file within Android Instrumentation context

Tags: android, testing, android-context, instrumentation

I have a class that creates (or opens) a file to write some data to it. This class receives a Context in the constructor, saves it in an instance field, and then uses it to call the context.openFileOutput method.

When running the application, I instantiate this class by passing the ApplicationContext as the Context, and everything is working as expected.

However, when I try to test this class with an Instrumentation Test, I get a `NullPointerException`. I'm passing the `getInstrumentation().getContext()` context, which I know corresponds to the context of the test, and not the one of the real app.

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().openFileOutput("myFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // This throws NullPointerException :( :(
```

Within the test, I need this file to be created in the test package and not in the app package, as I don't want overwrite the file in my app.

I know there is a `RenamingDelegatingContext` class out there, but I cannot pass this context to my class since my class also opens a raw resource, and I want that resource to be different when running the test (something like a mocked resource).

I searched a lot about this, and there is no documentation about the Instrumentation Context. I couldn't find its limitations nor anything that solves my problem.

Do you know how to tackle this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

I can't recall when this was changed, but the current method to get a `Context` object during Instrumented testing is to import

```java
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
```

and call

```java
InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
```

Hope this helps!